# Which reflection groups contain central inversion?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, representation-theory, symmetry, discrete-geometry

> **Question:**
> Which finite irreducible [reflection groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_group) $\Gamma\subseteq\mathrm O(\Bbb R^d)$ contain the central inversion $-\mathrm{Id}$, and how can this be spotted from the [Coxeter diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter%E2%80%93Dynkin_diagram)?

The following groups do not have central inversion:

- $I_2(n)$ for odd $n\ge 3$,
- $A_d$ for all $d\ge 3$,
- $D_d$ for odd $d\ge 3$, and
- $E_6$.

I am not sure about $E_7$ and $E_8$. All others do have central inversion.
The emphasize of my question is on the second part: is there combinatorial data in the Coxeter diagram from which to infer whether $-\mathrm{Id}\in\Gamma$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59783/properties-of-the-longest-element-in-a-weyl-group

Comment: If Dynkin diagram admits no nontrivial involutions then $-1=w_0\in W$.